# script to continously scroll to the bottom on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that does infinite scrolling and I wanted to do some performance testing on it by scrolling endlessly to the bottom of the page.

Is there a jQuery/javascript command that allows me to scroll continously on a page non-stop?

I tried doing the following:

```
   for (var i=0;i<100;i++)
{ 
    setTimeout(window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight), i * 10000);
}
```

basically I wanted to call window.scrollTo .. after delayed for 5 seconds, and then calling it again.. infinitely. However the solution above doesn't work. I don't care about this being hacky, I just needed something to work for testing.

Comment: There's definitely numerous ways to accomplish this, let us see your attempts.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy see my answer above

Comment: why do you need a script when you can use your mouse middle click and scroll continuously to the bottom

Comment: @guleria I wanted this to work on multiple page, so say I open up 10 tabs, and I want those 10 tabs to scroll continously.. As I said this is for stress testing

Comment: Giving `setTimeout` is not a good idea..wat page are you scrolling? Is it using `jQuery Ajax` for Infinite scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/52jzM/515/):

**CSS:**

```
body{
    height:400px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var body = $('body');
setInterval(function(){
    var pos = div.scrollTop();
    div.scrollTop(pos + n);  // you can have your offset
}, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
```